# How can I re-scale the text of homepage on phone preview?

Tags: css, text, responsive, cover

We have a problem with the text **"A GOLDEN JOURNEY TO EVERYWHERE"** on the home page of [our website](https://mineteams.com/)

The text on the homepage is in large scale and there’s no problem with monitor/ tablet screen preview of it. But for mobile phone screen, the text won’t be re-scaled and it is too large that it won’t be shown completely on phone screen and a few letters are missing from each side.

How can I  customize the text’s size also for phone preview to solve this problem.

**CSS code :**

````
/** Start Block Kit CSS: 144-3-3a7d335f39a8579c20cdf02f8d462582 **/

.envato-block__preview{overflow: visible;}

/* Envato Kit 141 Custom Styles - Applied to the element under Advanced */

.elementor-headline-animation-type-drop-in .elementor-headline-dynamic-wrapper{
   text-align: center;
}
.envato-kit-141-top-0 h1,
.envato-kit-141-top-0 h2,
.envato-kit-141-top-0 h3,
.envato-kit-141-top-0 h4,
.envato-kit-141-top-0 h5,
.envato-kit-141-top-0 h6,
.envato-kit-141-top-0 p {
   margin-top: 0;
}

.envato-kit-141-newsletter-inline .elementor-field-textual.elementor-size-md {
   padding-left: 1.5rem;
   padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

.envato-kit-141-bottom-0 p {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

.envato-kit-141-bottom-8 .elementor-price-list .elementor-price-list-item .elementor-price-list-header {
   margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.envato-kit-141.elementor-widget-testimonial-carousel.elementor-pagination-type-bullets .swiper-container {
   padding-bottom: 52px;
}

.envato-kit-141-display-inline {
   display: inline-block;
}

.envato-kit-141 .elementor-slick-slider ul.slick-dots {
   bottom: -40px;
}

.pth-hero__background-inner {
background-size: contain !important;
}

.light.css {
   font-size:70%
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
   div.pth-hero__message.skrollable.skrollable-between h2{ 
           
           letter-spacing: -3PT;
}
   
/** End Block Kit CSS: 144-3-3a7d335f39a8579c20cdf02f8d462582 **/ ```
````

Comment: Have you tried just setting a smaller font size for narrow viewports? Or even make the fontsize proportional to viewport width (vw units)?

Answer (score 0):

Since 'clamp' arrived in all major browsers there is a very convenient way to define a responsive font size with a minimum and a maximum size:

```
// using clamp for responsive font sizes:
clamp([min-size], [default-size], [max-size]);


.myText {
  font-size: clamp(1em, 2.5vw, 3em);
}
```